# Problem with Replace function

Tags: functions, replacement

I recently started using *Mathematica*. I'm not able to understand my mistake. I'm trying to implement the Frangi vesselness for the enanchement of vessels in biomedical images. I wrote these functions:

```
gD[im_, nx_, ny_, Sigma_] := 
  (Sqrt[Sigma^2])^nx*(Sqrt[Sigma^2])^ny*(GaussianDerivative[{Sigma^2/2, nx}, 
   {Sigma^2/2, ny}][im])

Rb[e1_, e2_] := e2/e1; 

S[e1_, e2_] := Sqrt[e1^2 + e2^2];

Nu[im_, e1_, e2_, C_] := 
  Module[{rb, s}, 
    Which[
      e1 > 0, 0, 
      True, Exp[-(rb^2/(2*0.5^2))] (1 - Exp[-(s^2/(2*C))]) /. 
              {rb -> Rb[e1, e2], s -> S[e1, e2]}]];

vesselness[im_, Sigma_] := 
  Module[{
      k1 = Eigenvalues[hessian2D][[1]] /.
             Derivative[nx_, ny_][L_][x_, y_] -> gD[im,nx, ny, Sigma], 
      k2 = Eigenvalues[hessian2D][[2]] /.
             Derivative[nx_, ny_][L_][x_, y_] -> gD[im, nx, ny, Sigma], 
      c1, c2 = Table[c1, {Dimensions[im][[1]]}, {Dimensions[im][[2]]}]},
    MapThread[Nu, {im, k1, k2, c2}, 2] /. c1 -> 0.5*Max[S[k1, k2]]];

vesselness[subImage, 2]
```

I obtain this output:

```
{{2.31845*10^-8 (1 - E^(-25.5872/c1)), 0.0464587 (1 - E^(-19.4567/c1)), 
    0.70802 (1 - E^(-21.9183/c1)), 0.998914 (1 - E^(-29.5683/c1)), ...
```

The variable c1 is not replaced. Why?

Two expressions from comments in more readable form:

```
hessian2D = {{Derivative[2, 0][L][x, y], Derivative[1, 1][L][x, y]}, 
 {Derivative[1, 1][L][x, y], Derivative[0, 2][L][x, y]}}

gD[im_List, nx_, ny_, σ_] := Module[{x, y, kx, ky, mid, tmp}, 
        kx = N[Table[Evaluate[D[gauss[x, σ], {x, nx}]], {x, -6 σ, 6 σ}]]; 
        ky = If[nx == ny, kx, N[Table[Evaluate[
                            D[gauss[y, σ], {y, ny}]], {y, -6 σ, 6 σ}]]]; 
        mid = Ceiling[Length[#1]/2] &; 
        tmp = Transpose[ListConvolve[{kx}, im, {{1, mid[kx]}, {1, mid[kx]}}]]; 
        Transpose[ListConvolve[{ky}, tmp, {{1, mid[ky]}, {1, mid[ky]}}]]];
```

Comment: You realize it is absolutely impossible to test this since function definitions are missing?

Comment: Unfortunately GaussianDerivative is a function inside a toolbox and I don't know the implementation.
Hessian2D is the hessian matrix but I'm not able to post its implementation.

Comment: An alternative route might be to show `hessian2D` and maybe make up some function for `gD` that has the same general appearance as whatever it is ` GaussianDerivative` produces.

Comment: `hessian2D = ( {
   {\!\(
     \*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x, x\)]\(L[x, y]\)\), \!\(
     \*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x, y\)]\(L[x, y]\)\)},
   {\!\(
     \*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x, y\)]\(L[x, y]\)\), \!\(
     \*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(y, y\)]\(L[x, y]\)\)}
  } )`

Comment: `gD[im_List, nx_, ny_, \[Sigma]_] := 
     Module[{x, y, kx, ky, mid, tmp}, 
           kx = N[Table[Evaluate[D[gauss[x, \[Sigma]], {x, nx}]], 
              {x, -6 \[Sigma], 6 \[Sigma]}]]; 
        ky = 
    If[nx == ny, kx, N[Table[Evaluate[D[gauss[y, \[Sigma]], {y, ny}]], 
                {y, -6 \[Sigma], 6 \[Sigma]}]]]; 
   mid = Ceiling[Length[#1]/2] & ; 
        tmp = 
    Transpose[ListConvolve[{kx}, im, {{1, mid[kx]}, {1, mid[kx]}}]]; 
        Transpose[
    ListConvolve[{ky}, tmp, {{1, mid[ky]}, {1, mid[ky]}}]]]; `

Comment: If you can run that and not get a slew of error messages then you are faring better than I at the moment. Point being, stand-alone code is necessary in order to have a solid chance of replicating the problem.

Comment: This might have to do with you using a built-in symbol name (C) in the definition of Nu

Answer (score 6):

Here's the problem in a nutshell:

```
Module[{c1, c2 = foo[c1]}, c2 /. c1 -> value]
(*
==> foo[c1]
*)
```

The point is, `Module` replaces `c1` by a local variable in its body, but *not* in later assignments in the variable list. You can see what happens by just looking at the variables:

```
Module[{c1, c2 = foo[c1]}, {c1,c2}]
(*
==> {c1$184, foo[c1]}
*)
```

You see, `c1` in the list is replaced by the temporary variable `c1$184`, but `c2` evaluates to `foo[c1]`, not `foo[c1$184]`. Therefore when your replacement rule is to be evaluated, Mathematica ultimately sees

```
foo[c1] /. c1$184 -> value
```

and therefore determines that there's nothing to replace.

The solution is to put the assignment into the body of `Module`:

```
Module[{c1, c2}, c2 = foo[c1]; c2 /. c1 -> value]
(*
==> foo[value]
*)
```

Since now the expression `foo[c1]` is inside the body, it is replaced with the temporary variable, and everything works as intended.

Comment: I encounter this sort of problem all the time.  Nice job giving a concise description.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the problem only lies with c1, c2 and the Table, and ignoring any error message, if I use a self-constructed minimal working example

```
c1 = "I'm GLOBAL";
vesselness[im_, Sigma_] := 
 Module[{k1 = BAR1, k2 = BAR2, c1, c2 = c1},
   {im, k1, k2, c2} /. c1 -> "I'm local"
];
vesselness[subIm, ref]
```

the result is

```
{subIm, BAR1, BAR2, "I'm GLOBAL"}
```

Either replacing `Module` with `Block`,

```
vesselness[im_, Sigma_] := Block[ etc....
```

or assigning the value to c2 later in the Module,

```
c1 = "I'm GLOBAL";
vesselness[im_, Sigma_] := 
 Module[{k1 = BAR1, k2 = BAR2, c1, c2 = c1},
   {im, k1, k2, c2} /. c1 -> "I'm local"
];
vesselness[subIm, ref]
```

outputs the replaced version:

```
{subIm, BAR1, BAR2, "I'm local"}
```

Since Module creates new, local variables that just happen to be addressed with the same name by us users, it seems that during the "defining local variables" phase Module still uses globally scoped variables, whereas in the body, they are correctly replaced.